# Gradient Descent Using List Storage Resulting in Division by Zero Error in Image Processing Algorithm for Multi-Variable Optimization

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, mathematical-optimization, gradient-descent

I'm working on an optimization algorithm that utilizes Gradient Ascent to adjust my parameters `focus`, `second_dispersion`, and `third_dispersion`. Since I'm working with a physical system I don't have a known function to maximize, but instead I rely on a closed loop using list storage to keep track of the value of my function: `count(focus,second_dispersion,third_dispersion)`.

Accordingly, to take the "partial derivatives" I rely on `(self.count_history[-1]-self.count_history[-2])/(self.third_dispersion_history[-1]-self.third_dispersion_history[-2])` for each parameter.

Since for my purposes I have the new parameter value to be a whole number, if the change isn't significant enough the code will result in the same value leading to a division by zero error.

To counter this I thought of using something like the following for every optimized parameter:

```py
        try:
            if (self.third_dispersion_history[-1] != self.third_dispersion_history[-2]):
                self.count_third_dispersion_der = (self.count_history[-1] - self.count_history[-2]) / (self.third_dispersion_history[-1] - self.third_dispersion_history[-2])
            else:
                self.count_third_dispersion_der = 0
        except (ZeroDivisionError, IndexError):
            self.count_third_dispersion_der = 0
```

Still, since I rely on the derivative value for the new value of the parameter this idea fails and spirals to a loop that doesn't allow optimization. I'm also plotting the graphs of the partial derivatives against iteration, and so I need to make sure that the lists always have the same length. How could I effectively solve this issue?

This is my full code (not working) where the function `optimize_count` needs to be modified:

```py
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from ftplib import FTP
import shutil
import random
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sys 
import time 
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from watchdog.observers import Observer

MIRROR_FILE_PATH = r'mirror_command/mirror_change.txt'
DISPERSION_FILE_PATH = r'dazzler_command/dispersion.txt'

with open(MIRROR_FILE_PATH, 'r') as file:
    content = file.read()
mirror_values = list(map(int, content.split()))

with open(DISPERSION_FILE_PATH, 'r') as file:
    content = file.readlines()

dispersion_values = {
    0: int(content[0].split('=')[1].strip()),  # 0 is the key for 'order2'
    1: int(content[1].split('=')[1].strip())   # 1 is the key for 'order3'
}

class ImageHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self, process_images_callback):
        super().__init__()
        self.process_images_callback = process_images_callback

    def on_created(self, event):
        if not event.is_directory:
            self.process_images_callback([event.src_path])
                      
class BetatronApplication(QtWidgets.QApplication):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BetatronApplication, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.mean_count_per_n_images  = 0
        self.count_grad = 0
        self.n_images = 4
        self.n_images_dir_run_count = 0
        self.n_images_run_count = 0
        self.run_count = 0
        self.n_images_count_sum = 0  
        self.record_count_history = []
        self.count_history = []
        self.focus_learning_rate = 0.001
        self.second_dispersion_learning_rate = 0.09
        self.third_dispersion_learning_rate = 0.09

        self.IMG_PATH = r'C:\Users\blehe\Desktop\Betatron\images'
        self.image_files = [os.path.join(self.IMG_PATH, filename) for filename in os.listdir(self.IMG_PATH) if filename.endswith('.png') and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(self.IMG_PATH, filename))]

        self.printed_message = False
        self.initialize_image_files()

    # ------------ Plotting ------------ #

        self.third_dispersion_der_history = []
        self.second_dispersion_der_history = []
        self.focus_der_history = []
        self.total_gradient_history = []

        self.iteration_data = []
        self.der_iteration_data = []
        self.count_data = []
        
        self.count_plot_widget = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.count_plot_widget.setWindowTitle('count optimization')
        self.count_plot_widget.setLabel('left', 'count')
        self.count_plot_widget.setLabel('bottom', 'n_images iteration')
        self.count_plot_widget.showGrid(x=True, y=True)
        self.count_plot_widget.show()

        self.main_plot_window = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
        self.main_plot_window.show()

        # Create a grid layout for subplots
        layout = self.main_plot_window.addLayout(row=0, col=0)

        self.count_plot_widget = layout.addPlot(title='count vs n_images iteration')
        self.focus_plot = layout.addPlot(title='count_focus_derivative')
        self.second_dispersion_plot = layout.addPlot(title='count_second_dispersion_derivative')
        self.third_dispersion_plot = layout.addPlot(title='count_third_dispersion_derivative')
        self.total_gradient_plot = layout.addPlot(title='total_gradient')

        subplots = [self.count_plot_widget, self.focus_plot, self.second_dispersion_plot, self.third_dispersion_plot, self.total_gradient_plot]
        for subplot in subplots:
            subplot.showGrid(x=True, y=True)

        # Create separate PlotItems for plotting curves
        self.plot_curve = self.count_plot_widget.plot(pen='r')
        self.focus_curve = self.focus_plot.plot(pen='r', name='focus derivative')
        self.second_dispersion_curve = self.second_dispersion_plot.plot(pen='g', name='second dispersion derivative')
        self.third_dispersion_curve = self.third_dispersion_plot.plot(pen='b', name='third dispersion derivative')
        self.total_gradient_curve = self.total_gradient_plot.plot(pen='y', name='total gradient')

        # Update the setData calls accordingly
        self.plot_curve.setData(self.iteration_data, self.count_history)
        self.focus_curve.setData(self.der_iteration_data, self.focus_der_history)
        self.second_dispersion_curve.setData(self.der_iteration_data, self.second_dispersion_der_history)
        self.third_dispersion_curve.setData(self.der_iteration_data, self.third_dispersion_der_history)
        self.total_gradient_curve.setData(self.der_iteration_data, self.total_gradient_history)

    # ------------ Deformable mirror ------------ #

        # init -150
        self.MIRROR_HOST = "192.168.200.3"
        self.MIRROR_USER = "Utilisateur"
        self.MIRROR_PASSWORD = "alls"    

        self.initial_focus = mirror_values[0]
        self.focus_history = []    
        # self.FOCUS_LOWER_BOUND = max(self.initial_focus - 20, -200)
        # self.FOCUS_UPPER_BOUND = min(self.initial_focus + 20, 200)

        self.FOCUS_LOWER_BOUND = -999999
        self.FOCUS_UPPER_BOUND = 999999

        self.tolerance = 100
        
    # ------------ Dazzler ------------ #

        self.DAZZLER_HOST = "192.168.58.7"
        self.DAZZLER_USER = "fastlite"
        self.DAZZLER_PASSWORD = "fastlite"

        # 36100 initial 
        self.initial_second_dispersion = dispersion_values[0] 
        self.second_dispersion_history = []
        # self.SECOND_DISPERSION_LOWER_BOUND = max(self.initial_second_dispersion - 500, 30000)
        # self.SECOND_DISPERSION_UPPER_BOUND = min(self.initial_second_dispersion + 500, 40000)

        self.SECOND_DISPERSION_LOWER_BOUND = -999999
        self.SECOND_DISPERSION_UPPER_BOUND = 999999


        # -27000 initial
        self.initial_third_dispersion = dispersion_values[1] 
        self.third_dispersion_history = []
        # self.THIRD_DISPERSION_LOWER_BOUND = max(self.initial_third_dispersion -2000, -30000)
        # self.THIRD_DISPERSION_UPPER_BOUND = min(self.initial_third_dispersion + 2000, -25000)

        self.THIRD_DISPERSION_LOWER_BOUND = -999999
        self.THIRD_DISPERSION_UPPER_BOUND = 999999

        self.random_direction = []

        self.image_handler = ImageHandler(self.process_images)
        self.file_observer = Observer()
        self.file_observer.schedule(self.image_handler, path=self.IMG_PATH, recursive=False)
        self.file_observer.start()

        self.random_direction = [random.choice([-1, 1]) for _ in range(4)]

    def periodic_processing(self):
        self.process_images(self.image_files)
            
    def initialize_image_files(self):
        if not self.printed_message:
            print("Waiting for images ...")
            self.printed_message = True

        new_files = [os.path.join(self.IMG_PATH, filename) for filename in os.listdir(self.IMG_PATH) if filename.endswith('.png') and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(self.IMG_PATH, filename))]

        if new_files:
            self.image_files = new_files

    def upload_files(self):
        mirror_ftp = FTP()
        dazzler_ftp = FTP()

        mirror_ftp.connect(host=self.MIRROR_HOST)
        mirror_ftp.login(user=self.MIRROR_USER, passwd=self.MIRROR_PASSWORD)

        dazzler_ftp.connect(host=self.DAZZLER_HOST)
        dazzler_ftp.login(user=self.DAZZLER_USER, passwd=self.DAZZLER_PASSWORD)

        mirror_files = [os.path.basename(MIRROR_FILE_PATH)]
        dazzler_files = [os.path.basename(DISPERSION_FILE_PATH)]

        for mirror_file_name in mirror_files:
            for dazzler_file_name in dazzler_files:
                focus_file_path = MIRROR_FILE_PATH
                dispersion_file_path = DISPERSION_FILE_PATH

                if os.path.isfile(focus_file_path) and os.path.isfile(dispersion_file_path):
                    copy_mirror_IMG_PATH = os.path.join('mirror_command', f'copy_{mirror_file_name}')
                    copy_dazzler_IMG_PATH = os.path.join('dazzler_command', f'copy_{dazzler_file_name}')

                    try:
                        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(copy_mirror_IMG_PATH))
                        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(copy_dazzler_IMG_PATH))
                    except OSError:
                        pass

                    shutil.copy(focus_file_path, copy_mirror_IMG_PATH)
                    shutil.copy(dispersion_file_path, copy_dazzler_IMG_PATH)

                    with open(copy_mirror_IMG_PATH, 'rb') as local_file:
                        mirror_ftp.storbinary(f'STOR {mirror_file_name}', local_file)
                        print(f"Uploaded to mirror FTP: {mirror_file_name}")

                    with open(copy_dazzler_IMG_PATH, 'rb') as local_file:
                        dazzler_ftp.storbinary(f'STOR {dazzler_file_name}', local_file)
                        print(f"Uploaded to dazzler FTP: {dazzler_file_name}")

                    os.remove(copy_mirror_IMG_PATH)
                    os.remove(copy_dazzler_IMG_PATH)

    def calc_xray_count(self, image_path):
        original_image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED | cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
        median_filtered_image = cv2.medianBlur(original_image, 5)
        img_mean_count = median_filtered_image.mean()

        return img_mean_count

    def initial_optimize(self):

        self.new_focus = self.focus_history[-1] + self.random_direction[0]
        self.new_second_dispersion = self.second_dispersion_history[-1] + self.random_direction[1]
        self.new_third_dispersion = self.third_dispersion_history[-1] + self.random_direction[2]
 
        self.new_focus = round(np.clip(self.new_focus, self.FOCUS_LOWER_BOUND, self.FOCUS_UPPER_BOUND))
        self.new_second_dispersion = round(np.clip(self.new_second_dispersion, self.SECOND_DISPERSION_LOWER_BOUND, self.SECOND_DISPERSION_UPPER_BOUND))
        self.new_third_dispersion = round(np.clip(self.new_third_dispersion, self.THIRD_DISPERSION_LOWER_BOUND, self.THIRD_DISPERSION_UPPER_BOUND))
 
        self.focus_history.append(self.new_focus)
        self.second_dispersion_history.append(self.new_second_dispersion)
        self.third_dispersion_history.append(self.new_third_dispersion)
 
        mirror_values[0] = (self.focus_history[-1])
        dispersion_values[0] = (self.second_dispersion_history[-1])
        dispersion_values[1] = (self.third_dispersion_history[-1])

    def optimize_count(self):
        try:
            if (self.focus_history[-1] != self.focus_history[-2]):
                self.count_focus_der = (self.count_history[-1] - self.count_history[-2]) / (self.focus_history[-1] -self.focus_history[-2])
        except (ZeroDivisionError, IndexError):
            self.count_focus_der = 0

        try:
            if (self.second_dispersion_history[-1] != self.second_dispersion_history[-2]):
                self.count_second_dispersion_der = (self.count_history[-1] - self.count_history[-2]) / (self.second_dispersion_history[-1] - self.second_dispersion_history[-2])
        except (ZeroDivisionError, IndexError):  
            self.count_second_dispersion_der = 0

        try:
            if (self.third_dispersion_history[-1] != self.third_dispersion_history[-2]):
                self.count_third_dispersion_der = (self.count_history[-1] - self.count_history[-2]) / (self.third_dispersion_history[-1] - self.third_dispersion_history[-2])
        except (ZeroDivisionError, IndexError):
            self.count_third_dispersion_der = 0

        if self.n_images_run_count >= 2:
            self.total_gradient = (self.focus_der_history[-1] + self.second_dispersion_der_history[-1] + self.third_dispersion_der_history[-1])
            self.total_gradient_history.append(self.total_gradient)

        if np.abs(self.count_history[-1] - self.count_history[-2]) <= self.tolerance:
            print("convergence achieved")

        else:
            self.new_focus = self.focus_history[-1] + self.focus_learning_rate * self.focus_der_history[-1]
            self.new_second_dispersion = self.second_dispersion_history[-1] + self.second_dispersion_learning_rate * self.second_dispersion_der_history[-1]
            self.new_third_dispersion = self.third_dispersion_history[-1] + self.third_dispersion_learning_rate * self.third_dispersion_der_history[-1]

            self.new_focus = np.clip(self.new_focus, self.FOCUS_LOWER_BOUND, self.FOCUS_UPPER_BOUND)
            self.new_second_dispersion = np.clip(self.new_second_dispersion, self.SECOND_DISPERSION_LOWER_BOUND, self.SECOND_DISPERSION_UPPER_BOUND)
            self.new_third_dispersion = np.clip(self.new_third_dispersion, self.THIRD_DISPERSION_LOWER_BOUND, self.THIRD_DISPERSION_UPPER_BOUND)

            self.new_focus = round(self.new_focus)
            self.new_second_dispersion = round(self.new_second_dispersion)
            self.new_third_dispersion = round(self.new_third_dispersion)

            self.focus_history.append(self.new_focus)
            self.second_dispersion_history.append(self.new_second_dispersion)
            self.third_dispersion_history.append(self.new_third_dispersion)

            mirror_values[0] = self.focus_history[-1]
            dispersion_values[0] = self.second_dispersion_history[-1]
            dispersion_values[1] = self.third_dispersion_history[-1]

            self.der_iteration_data.append(self.n_images_dir_run_count)
            self.focus_der_history.append(self.count_focus_der)
            self.second_dispersion_der_history.append(self.count_second_dispersion_der)
            self.third_dispersion_der_history.append(self.count_third_dispersion_der)


    def process_images(self, new_images):
        self.initialize_image_files() 
        new_images = [image_path for image_path in new_images if os.path.exists(image_path)]
        new_images.sort(key=os.path.getctime)

        for image_path in new_images:
            relative_path = os.path.relpath(image_path, self.IMG_PATH)
            img_mean_count = self.calc_xray_count(image_path)
            self.n_images_count_sum += np.sum(img_mean_count)

            self.run_count += 1

            if self.run_count % self.n_images == 0:
                self.mean_count_per_n_images = np.mean(img_mean_count)
                self.count_history.append(self.mean_count_per_n_images)
                self.n_images_run_count += 1
                self.iteration_data.append(self.n_images_run_count)

                if self.n_images_run_count == 1:
                    print('-------------')                    
                    self.focus_history.append(self.initial_focus)                       
                    self.second_dispersion_history.append(self.initial_second_dispersion)
                    self.third_dispersion_history.append(self.initial_third_dispersion)      
                    print(f"initial values are: focus {self.focus_history[-1]}, second_dispersion {self.second_dispersion_history[-1]}, third_dispersion {self.third_dispersion_history[-1]}")
                    print(f"initial directions are: focus {self.random_direction[0]}, second_dispersion {self.random_direction[1]}, third_dispersion {self.random_direction[2]}")
                    self.initial_optimize()

                else:
                    self.n_images_dir_run_count += 1
                    self.optimize_count()

                with open(MIRROR_FILE_PATH, 'w') as file:
                    file.write(' '.join(map(str, mirror_values)))

                with open(DISPERSION_FILE_PATH, 'w') as file:
                    file.write(f'order2 = {dispersion_values[0]}\n')
                    file.write(f'order3 = {dispersion_values[1]}\n')

                QtCore.QCoreApplication.processEvents()

                # print(f"{relative_path}, {self.count_history[-1]}, current values are: focus {self.focus_history[-1]}, second_dispersion {self.second_dispersion_history[-1]}, third_dispersion {self.third_dispersion_history[-1]}") 
                print(f"mean_count_per_{self.n_images}_images {self.count_history[-1]}, current values are: focus {self.focus_history[-1]}, second_dispersion {self.second_dispersion_history[-1]}, third_dispersion {self.third_dispersion_history[-1]}")
                
                # self.upload_files() # send files to second computer

                self.plot_curve.setData(self.iteration_data, self.count_history)
                self.focus_curve.setData(self.der_iteration_data, self.focus_der_history)
                self.second_dispersion_curve.setData(self.der_iteration_data, self.second_dispersion_der_history)
                self.third_dispersion_curve.setData(self.der_iteration_data, self.third_dispersion_der_history)
                self.total_gradient_curve.setData(self.der_iteration_data, self.total_gradient_history)


                self.n_images_count_sum = 0
                self.mean_count_per_n_images  = 0
                img_mean_count = 0  
                print('-------------')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = BetatronApplication([])
    win = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```